# How to add msi scope to another RG in azure using templates

Tags: azure, templates, azure-managed-identity

I have a MSI in 'x' RG. I am able to set its scope to the RG.
Question is- I want to add the MSI scope to another RG - "xx" as well using templates. Below is my template snippet:

```
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
      "name": "[variables('msi_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-30",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2018-12-01-preview",
      "name": "[guid(resourceGroup().id)]",
      "dependsOn": [
          "vmsCopy",
          "[concat('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', variables('msi_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
          "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('roleType'))]",
          "principalId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/',variables('msi_name'))).principalId]",
          "scope": "resourceGroup().id"
      }
    },
      {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2018-12-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(guid(concat(resourceGroup().id),'_1'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
          "vmsCopy",
          "[concat('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', variables('msi_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
          "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('roleType'))]",
          "principalId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/',variables('msi_name'))).principalId]",
          "scope": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourcegroups/','xx')]"
      }
    }
```

Getting following error everytime -
/subscriptions//resourceGroups/xx' must match the scope specified on the URI '/subscriptions//resourcegroups/x'."
Both RGs are in same subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap the second role assignment with a deployment into another rg:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "name": "subnet-role-assignment",
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
    "resourceGroup": "second_rg_name",
    "dependsOn": [
        "vmsCopy",
        "[concat('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', variables('msi_name'))]"
    ],
    "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
        "scope": "inner"
    },
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
                    "apiVersion": "2018-12-01-preview",
                    "name": "[concat(guid(concat(resourceGroup().id),'_1'))]",
                    "properties": {
                        "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('roleType'))]",
                        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('first_rg_name', 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', variables('msi_name'))).principalId]",
                        "scope": "[resourceGroup().id]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```